# Printing Text and Image in 1 PDF File

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, printing

I have a problem with printing data and image in PDF. I use the code below and it print image and data separately. But I want them to be in one PDF, how can I do this?

```
PrintDialog export = new PrintDialog();
string data = "data";
System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument flowDoc = new System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument(new System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph(new System.Windows.Documents.Run(data)));
System.Windows.Documents.IDocumentPaginatorSource source = flowDoc;
var result = export.ShowDialog();
if(result == true)
{
    export.PrintVisual(souradnySystem, "Visual");
    export.PrintDocument(source.DocumentPaginator, "Text");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the image to the FlowDocument before proceeding to print.
Assuming "souradnySystem" is your image (System.Windows.Controls.Image), it will be like the following:

```
string data = "data";
FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run(data)));
flowDoc.Blocks.Add(new BlockUIContainer(souradnySystem));
```